# Egit: can several projects co-exist in one local repository

Tags: egit

I am using egit and one thing really confuses me. Suppose I have a directory `/home/me/git`, and I would like to put several repositories in it.

For example, the first time I share a project, say `firsProject`, I can designate the local repository as `/home/me/git` (because it is empty). And the project's root directory is `/home/me/git/firstProject`.

Later, when I try to share another project, say `secondProject`, I won't be able to use `/home/me/git` as its local repository because it is not empty. I end up with using `/home/me/git/secondProject` as the repository, and the project's root directory is then `/home/me/git/secondProject/secodProject`.

Is it possible to have the following structure?

```
/home/me/git/firstProject
/home/me/git/secondProject
```

How can I do it?

Note: the firstProjcet and the secondProject are two separate repositories, managed by two development teams, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

What version of EGit are you using? The easiest way is this:

1. In the project context menu, choose Team > Share Project... and select Git
2. Make sure "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" is not checked
3. Select the `/home/me/git/` repository
4. Leave "Path within repository" empty
5. Finish the wizard

Another way is this:

1. In the project context menu, choose Move... (or Refactor > Move...)
2. Create a new empty folder `/home/me/git/secondProject` and use that as the Location
3. Use Team > Sahre Project...
4. "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" should be checked now and you can just finish the wizard

Comment: Following your suggestions: For the fresh first project (say, firstProject), it worked OK and a new repository /home/me/git was created.  But when I tried to clone a second project from github: File --> Import --> Git: Project from Git --> Clone URI --> URI: ..., ... --> Next --> Next --> Directory: ... 

Here if I input "/home/me/git", Eclipse would complain that it is not an empty directory. If I input /home/me/git/secondProject, then another repository named secondProject was created. Now I have two repositories: /home/me/git and /home/me/git/secondProjcet. Is this normal? Thanks again.

Comment: I think that having two repositories is right. But firstProject's .git folder resides in /home/me/git, whereas secondProject's .git folder resides in /home/me/git/secondFolder. Shouldn't firstProject's .git folder resides in /home/me/git/firstFolder?

Comment: By the way, your second method didn't seem to work because at Step 4, the "Finish" button is grayed out and Eclipse won't let the check box been checked. A message is displayed: Creation of repositories in the Eclipse workspace is not recommended.

Comment: Ah, so you have 2 separate repositories?  You didn't mention this in the question. Do you want to merge the repositories?

Comment: I found the rule of egit. Suppose I have a directory /home/me/git for holding git repositories: 

1) When I share a project called firstProject, /home/me/git would contains firstProject directory, in which there are two directories: .git and firstProjcect.


2) When I share another project called secondProject, /home/me/git would contains two directories: firstProject and secondProject. And secondProjcet directory have two directories in it: .git and secondProject.

Although I think having two directories with the same name is totally unnecessary, well, that's how egit does it. Am I right?